# fetch request for entity.attribute == @"somevalue"

Tags: core-data, attributes, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

How do I setup a fetch request to only pull the data from an entity's attribute with one particular value? This is the basic code I've used before.

```m
-(void)fetchResults
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:self.entityDescription.name];
    NSString *cacheName = [self.entityDescription.name stringByAppendingString:@"Cache"];

    // predicate code
    if (self.predicate != nil) {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:self.predicate];
    }
    // end of predicate code

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:cacheName];

    BOOL success;
    NSError *error;
    success = [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    if (!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

I've been looking at this page: http://bit.ly/KevYwR is this the right direction?

Do I need to use `NSPredicate` or can I do without?

Thanks for any help, point in the right direction, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Setting up a `NSFetchRequest` is equivalent to a SELECT statetement in SQL language.

Here a simple example:

```m
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

// error handling code
```

The array `results` contains all the managed objects contained within the sqlite file. If you want to grab a specific object (or more objects) you need to use a predicate with that request. For example:

```m
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute == %@", @"Some Value"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

In this case `results` contains the objects where attribute is equal to `Some Value`. Setting a predicate is equal to put the WHERE clause in a SQL statement.

**Note**

I suppose that the name of the entity is `EntityName` and its property is called `attribute` which is of type string.

For further info I suggest you to read the Core Data programming guide and `NSFecthRequest` class reference.

- http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html

Hope it helps.