# How to check if object exists in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, core-data

I've searched answer here, but none of these solved my problem... 
I've saved some data in core data, in Truck `Managed Object Subclass`. Here's the code:

```
for (NSDictionary *dictTruck in self.trucksArray) {
        Truck *truck = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Truck" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
        Country *country = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

        NSFetchRequest *truckRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        NSEntityDescription *truckDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Truck" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
        [truckRequest setEntity:truckDescription];
        NSMutableArray *mutableReq = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:truckRequest error:nil]mutableCopy];
        self.trucksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:mutableReq];
        [truck setModel:[dictTruck objectForKey:@"model"]];
        [truck setYear:[dictTruck objectForKey:@"year"]];
        [truck setCountry:country];
        [country setCountryName:[dictTruck objectForKey:@"country"]];
        [_managedObjectContext save:nil];

    }
```

And this works pretty fine. Now, problem is that I have JSON that I'm downloading from server via `AFNetworking` in format like this:

```
{
    "trucks": [
        {
            "model": "Scania",
            "year": "2014",
            "country": "Sweden"
        },
        {
            "model": "DAF",
            "year": "2012",
            "country": "Ireland"
        }
    ]
}
```

This JSON is updated every hour, so there is old JSON data + new... Now, my question is how can I check if this object exists in Core Data, example: Truck.model = @"Scania", Truck.year = @"2014", Truck.Country.countryName = @"Sweden"; And if it matches all this conditions it should not be saved in CD...
Thanks in advance. 
**Update:
 In this code is piece of request for objects in core data, because I've tried so many ways to solve this.**

Comment: You need to use NSFetchRequest along with NSPredicate to look up to a specific record: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612955/fetch-request-for-entity-attribute-somevalue

Comment: Could you be more specific, because I created NSFetchRequest, but problem is that I don't know how to set condition to check if it is satisfied.

Comment: That is what the NSPredicate is for.  In the link I posted, if the fetched result is negative then you know...  I am not at a computer stackoverflow.com I can't write code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there should be a **UNIQUE** `truck_id` in the response json, like this

```
{
    "trucks": [
        {
            "id": "00000001"
            "model": "Scania",
            "year": "2014",
            "country": "Sweden"
        },
        {
            "id": "00000002"
            "model": "DAF",
            "year": "2012",
            "country": "Ireland"
        }
    ]
}
```

Save the `id` to `Truck` model and every time you get response from server, just check if there is a model with same `id` in core data.

For every truck json, make a fetch request first

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Truck" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"truckID = %d", truckIDInResponse];
request.predicate = predicate;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objs = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error) {
    [NSException raise:@"no truck find" format:@"%@", [error localizedDescription]];
}
if (objs.count > 0) {
    // there is a truck with same id exsist. Use update method
}else {
    // there's no truck with same id. Use insert method
}
```

The `truckID` is the property of your `Truck` model.

Comment: Yeah, good opinion. Could u help me with the checking if id exists in core data?

Comment: @Stefan Update my answer