# Property access result unused error while invoking a method

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using the following code to invoke a method,

```
APIRequest *apiRequest = [[APIRequest alloc]init];
apiRequest.pendingShipmentDetails ;
```

Im getting the following warning,

> property access result unused getters should not be used for side
>   effects

what does it mean?

and the method is getting called twice at the same time

Following is my method,

```
-(void)pendingShipmentDetails
{
    keyChain = [[KeyChainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"LoginController" accessGroup:nil];
    NSString *username = [keyChain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrLabel)];

    NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"method\":\"pending_shipment_details\",\"data\":{\"username\":\"%@\"}}",username];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];
    NSData *postData = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if ([data length] > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             [self receivedPendingShipmentDetailsData:data];
             NSString* pendingResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSData *jsonData = [pendingResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
             NSDictionary *valueDict = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"];

             NSArray *details = [valueDict objectForKey:@"details"];

             NSMutableArray* arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

             for (NSDictionary *response in details) {
                 NSString *invoiceNo = [response valueForKey:@"invoice_no"];
                 NSString *shipmentNumber = [response valueForKey:@"shipment_no"];
                 NSString *invoiceDate = [response valueForKey:@"invoice_date"];
                 NSString *proformaInvoiceNumber = [response valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
                 NSString *proformaInvoiceDate = [response valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
                 NSString *plannedShipmentDates = [response valueForKey:@"planned_shipment_dates"];
                 NSString *pointOfContact =[[response objectForKey:@"point_of_contact"] valueForKey:@"empid"];
                 NSString *pendingStatus = [response valueForKey:@"status"];
                 NSDictionary *productName = [response valueForKey:@"products"];
                 NSDictionary *quantity = [response valueForKey:@"quantity"];
                 NSDictionary *rate = [response valueForKey:@"rate"];
                 NSDictionary *amount = [response valueForKey:@"amount"];
                 NSDictionary *productImages = [response valueForKey:@"product_image"];
                 NSDictionary *point_of_contact = [response valueForKey:@"point_of_contact"];

                 NSString *qty;
                 NSString *rte;
                 NSString *img;
                 NSString *address;
                 NSString *name;
                 NSString *amt;

                 for (int i = 0; i < [productName count]; i++) {
                     //  NSLog(@"product name %@",[productName valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]]);
                     name = [productName valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]];
                 }

                 for (int i = 0; i < [quantity count]; i++) {
                     //  NSLog(@"quantity %@",[quantity valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]]);
                     qty = [quantity valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]];
                 }

                 for (int i = 0; i < [rate count]; i++) {
                     //  NSLog(@"rate %@",[rate valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]]);
                     rte = [rate valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]];
                 }

                 for (int i = 0; i < [amount count]; i++) {
                     // NSLog(@"amount %@",[amount valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]]);
                     amt = [amount valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]];
                 }


                 for (int i = 0; i < [productImages count]; i++) {
                     // NSLog(@"product image %@",[productImages valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]]);
                     img = [productImages valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i ]];
                 }

                 for (int i = 0; i < [point_of_contact count]; i++) {
                     //  NSLog(@"pt of ct %@",[point_of_contact valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"empid" ]]);
                     address = [point_of_contact valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"empid" ]];
                 }


                 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

                 //update
                 if((self.pendingShipmentDAO) ) {
                     NSLog(@"update");
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"shipmentno"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:proformaInvoiceNumber forKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:proformaInvoiceDate forKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:invoiceNo forKey:@"invoice_no"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:invoiceDate forKey:@"invoice_date"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:plannedShipmentDates forKey:@"planned_shipment_date"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:address forKey:@"point_of_contact"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:address forKey:@"empid"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:name forKey:@"products"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:qty forKey:@"quantity"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:rte forKey:@"rate"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:amt forKey:@"amount"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:img forKey:@"product_image"];
                     [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:pendingStatus forKey:@"status"];
                 }else {

                     NSLog(@"create");

                     NSManagedObject *pendingShipment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];

                     // [self deleteAllPreviousData];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"shipmentno"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:proformaInvoiceNumber forKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:proformaInvoiceDate forKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:invoiceNo forKey:@"invoice_no"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:invoiceDate forKey:@"invoice_date"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:plannedShipmentDates forKey:@"planned_shipment_date"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:address forKey:@"point_of_contact"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:address forKey:@"empid"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:name forKey:@"products"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:qty forKey:@"quantity"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:rte forKey:@"rate"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:amt forKey:@"amount"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:img forKey:@"product_image"];
                     [pendingShipment setValue:pendingStatus forKey:@"status"];


                 }
             }
         }

         else if ([data length] == 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             [self emptyReply];
         }
         else if (connectionError != nil && connectionError.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut)
         {
             [self timedOut];
         }
         else if (connectionError != nil)
         {
             [self downloadError:connectionError];
         }
     }];

}
```

Comment: Show the class *declaration* (the `@interface` bit); there must be a `@property SomeType *pendingShipmentDetails;` there somewhere...

Comment: `@interface MyOrdersController ()
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *devices;
@end `

Answer (score 0):

Dot notation is used for properties (getting or setting) them. So here the compiler understands that you want to call the getter of `pendingShipmentDetails` which is not the case. You must use `[]` to call methods. Replace `apiRequest.pendingShipmentDetails` with `[apiRequest pendingShipmentDetails]` and the warning should disappear.

Comment: that works. can you please help me to rectify the second error as well?

Comment: else loop is being executed twice

Comment: "you want to call the setter"
  do you mean `getter` maybe?

Comment: im actually parsing the json and adding those contents to an entity of  core data. then, im creating a NSManagedObject instance, if no such instance exists previously. if it exists im trying to update the entities with newly fetched datas but it ain't happening. :(

Comment: Where do you set the value of `self.pendingShipmentDAO`?

Comment: In `APIRequest.m` file Im setting it as `@synthesize pendingShipmentDAO;`

Comment: and In APIRequest.h file, i have `@property (strong) NSManagedObjectModel *pendingShipmentDAO;
`

Comment: I mean, where do you assign a value to it? Like `self.pendingShipmentDAO = something`. A declared `@property` is nil by default.

Comment: im not assigning it anywhere.

Comment: From what I understand you want to check if the shippment already exists and update it if it does. So you should assign to `self.pendingShipmentDAO` the existing shippment if there is one or nil if it doesn't.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066936/how-to-check-if-object-exists-in-core-data answer on how to check if an entity already exists in core data.